# Spring Controller not invoked for html views in mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, spring-web

I want to create simple Spring MVC application with MAVEN on top of tomcat. It has a home screen with a login link, which when clicked should redirect to the login page. To achieve this i have created a login controller to return login.html. When login is clicked in home page. The problem i'am facing is that the MVC controller is not being triggered. Please help!!

[**This is my folder structure**:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9Mnl.jpg)
LoginController.java:

```
package com.bestbuy.tcs.mw.automation.controller;
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    //@Autowired
    //LoginService loginService;

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String showLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        System.out.println("inside ");
        return "/login";
    }
}
```

**/WEB-INF/web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>MiddlewareAutomation</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml</param-value> 
    </context-param>
    <listener> 
        <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class> 
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-servlet.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">
    <!-- <import resource="classpath:jbr/config/user-beans.xml" /> -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bestbuy.tcs.mw.controller" />    
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**/webapp/home.html:**

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Middleware Automation home!!!</h2>
<a href="login">Login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**/WEB-INF/views/login.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>middle ware automation login page</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**Homepage URL working** - displays

```
https://localhost:8080/middlewareAutomation/
```

**Login Page URL NOT Working** - throws 404, requested resource not available error.

```
https://localhost:8080/middlewareAutomation/login
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct version of second URL should be

```
https://localhost:8080/middlewareAutomation/login.html
```

Comment: Nope, that also did not work. I do not see the request getting mapped to controller, in the first place.